# Export org-mode subtrees at chapter level for LaTeX

Tags: org-mode, org-export, latex

I have a `DATE_TREE` logbook within an org-file that I would like to export to Latex, keeping the years at a level of a chapter:

```
* Logbook
:PROPERTIES:
:DATE_TREE:
:END:
** 2016
*** 2016-10 October     :ignore:
**** 2016-10-13 Thursday
***** Some logged thing
```

I have set up the `ignore` tab so that the desired LaTeX export would be

```
\chapter{2016}
\section{2016-10-13 Thursday}
\subsection{Some logged thing}
```

However, the default behavior of org-mode export is to have the first level of export be a section, so I get `\section{2016}`.

Is there a way to change this export behavior **only** for this `Logbook` tree, and not for the entire buffer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use a `latex_class` that allows chapters, e.g. the `book` class, which is included in `org-latex-classes` by default. However, the default behavior is to use a part as the top level structure, instead of a chapter.

If you don't want parts, you can create a new element in `org-latex-classes` like so:

```
(add-to-list 'org-latex-classes
           '("book-noparts"
              "\\documentclass{book}"
              ("\\chapter{%s}" . "\\chapter*{%s}")
              ("\\section{%s}" . "\\section*{%s}")
              ("\\subsection{%s}" . "\\subsection*{%s}")
              ("\\subsubsection{%s}" . "\\subsubsection*{%s}")
              ("\\paragraph{%s}" . "\\paragraph*{%s}")
              ("\\subparagraph{%s}" . "\\subparagraph*{%s}")))
```

Then you can simply add `#+latex_class: book-noparts` to the Org file. To apply this only to a subtree, you can instead set the `export_latex_class` property by going to the Logbook headline and pressing `C-c C-x p` (`org-set-property`).

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!